# Determine whether you can reach bitstring B from bitstring A using specific operations

Tags: algorithm, operation, bitstring

The question is, given two bitstrings A and B, determine whether you can reach B from A using the following operation:

Choose two indices i,j such that the values at both indices are the same, and the number of 1's and 0's in between i and j are greater than the number of 1's and 0's outside the interval, respectively. Then, flip the bit at both indices.

An example of an operation:
0001010001

0**0**01010**0**01
number of zeroes between: 3 > num zeroes outside = 2

number of ones between: 2 > num ones outside = 1

thus,
0101010101 is a valid change.

I tried iterating right to left by keeping track of the number of ones and zeroes on each side, and if the number of ones and zeroes on the right side is less than the left side, I performed an operation to try and shift all the 1's to the right side (I was trying to transform each bitstring into its lexicographically minimum reduced version, then compare to see whether they are the same) but this fails hidden test cases. (or I implemented it incorrectly, I'm not sure if the algorithm idea is correct).

Not posting the code because it's irrelevant. I just want algorithm help, not coding help.

[image: The problem in its original depiction]

It's a private codeforces gym problem so I can't send the link.

Comment: You need to post your code you tried.

Comment: The downvote was me, and it is because you are asking for what looks like a homework problem without providing a solution you tried yourself. Personally I have no issues with people asking academic questions to help them with a grade, but you need to post code to reference....what your question looks like, to me, is a pure academic question about an algorithm where you want us to solve the full problem for you without you really trying. SO is more of a collaborative forum (in my experience), you try something, we fix it and explain why, then you learn...

Comment: @ViaTech with all due respect, how does "I tried iterating right to left by keeping track of the number of ones and zeroes on each side, and if the number of ones and zeroes on the right side is less than the left side, I performed an operation to try and shift all the 1's to the right side (I was trying to transform each bitstring into its lexicographically minimum reduced version, then compare to see whether they are the same) but this fails hidden test cases. (or I implemented it incorrectly, I'm not sure if the algorithm idea is correct)." not count as an attempted solution?

Comment: The operation is choosing 2 indices as you describe, and then flipping them, correct? If that's right, please update the sentence about the operation to say so; if not, please clarify what the operation is after the indices are selected.

Comment: Are the values at i and j considered to be inside the interval, outside it, or neither?

Comment: Can you post a link to the problem, or share it exactly as it was given to you if it's not online?

Comment: Don't forget to check your school's academic honesty policy on obtaining outside assistance with assignments. You may need to cite this web site as a source of assistance.

Comment: @Dave just updated the post

Comment: Please share all clarification **in text form**, not hidden in screenshots

Comment: It still stands, you need to post your code, only then we can help you.

Comment: Why? This isn't code review. I'm not asking for coding help.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I stumbled across this post again. I think I did not understand the problem correctly the first time, because I thought that only players wo want to switch teams are allowed to actually switch.

If you are still interested please check if this code passes the tests.

```python
def main():
    t = int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        read_input_and_solve()


def read_input_and_solve():
    n = int(input())
    p = input()
    q = input()

    if solve(n, p, q): 
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')


def solve(n, p, q):
    try:       
        check_middle(n, p, q)
        r = find_index_right_min(n, p, q)
        l = find_index_left_max(n, p, q)
        
        if r:
            validate_switchable_1_j(p, r)
        if l:
            validate_switchable_i_n(p, l)

        check_balance(n, p, q)
        return True
    except NotSolvableException as e:
        return False


def check_balance(n, p, q):
    balanced = \
    sum(1 for i in range(0, n//2-1) if p[i-1] == 1 and q[i] == 0)  \
    - sum(1 for i in range(0, n//2-1) if p[i] == 0 and q[i] == 1) \
    == \
    sum(1 for i in range(n//2+1, n) if p[i] == 1 and q[i] == 0)  \
    - sum(1 for i in range(n//2+1, n) if p[i] == 0 and q[i] == 1)

    if not balanced:
        raise NotSolvableException('not balanced')  
  

def check_middle(n, p, q):
    middle_indices = [n//2-1, n//2]
    if any(map(lambda i: p[i] != q[i], middle_indices)):
        raise NotSolvableException(f'indices {n//2}, {n//2 + 1} cannot switch')  
        

def find_index_right_min(n, p, q):
    for j in range(n//2-1, n):
        if p[j] != q[j]:
            return j
    else: return None
        

def find_index_left_max(n, p, q):
    for i in range(n//2-2, -1, -1):
        if p[i] != q[i]:
            return i
    else: return None


def validate_switchable_i_n(p, i):
    n = len(p)

    inner_vote_A = sum(1 for k in range(i+1, n) if p[k] == 'A')
    outer_vote_A = sum(1 for k in range(i) if p[k] == 'A')

    if p[i] == 'A' and p[n-1] == 'B':
        outer_vote_A += 1
    if p[i] == 'B' and p[n-1] == 'A':
        outer_vote_A -= 1        

    if inner_vote_A <= outer_vote_A:
        raise NotSolvableException('transfer rejected')  

    inner_vote_B = sum(1 for k in range(i+1, n) if p[k] == 'B')
    outer_vote_B = sum(1 for k in range(i) if p[k] == 'B')

    if p[i] == 'A' and p[n-1] == 'B':
        outer_vote_B -= 1
    if p[i] == 'B' and p[n-1] == 'A':
        outer_vote_B += 1   

    if inner_vote_B <= outer_vote_B:
        raise NotSolvableException('transfer rejected') 
    
    
def validate_switchable_1_j(p, j):
    n = len(p)
    inner_vote_A = sum(1 for k in range(1, j) if p[k] == 'A')
    outer_vote_A = sum(1 for k in range(j+1, n) if p[k] == 'A')

    if p[j] == 'A' and p[0] == 'B':
        outer_vote_A += 1
    if p[j] == 'B' and p[0] == 'A':
        outer_vote_A -= 1        

    if inner_vote_A <= outer_vote_A:
        raise NotSolvableException('transfer rejected')  

    inner_vote_B = sum(1 for k in range(1, j) if p[k] == 'B')
    outer_vote_B = sum(1 for k in range(j+1, n) if p[k] == 'B')

    if p[j] == 'A' and p[0] == 'B':
        outer_vote_B -= 1
    if p[j] == 'B' and p[0] == 'A':
        outer_vote_B += 1   

    if inner_vote_B <= outer_vote_B:
        raise NotSolvableException('transfer rejected')     


def get_votes(prefix_sum_team, i, j):
    votes_no = prefix_sum_team[-1] - prefix_sum_team[j] 
    if i-1 >= 0:
        votes_no += prefix_sum_team[i-1]
    votes_yes = prefix_sum_team[j-1] - prefix_sum_team[i]
    return votes_yes, votes_no


class NotSolvableException(RuntimeError):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: It gives WA on Test 2:
https://i.imgur.com/naZNDZx.png

Comment: Any chance you can see the input of test 2?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/

Comment: I edited the post and added a new version.